PM2 - Current process list is not synchronized with saved list
I have a windows server where I have some code running. I am using pm2 to manage 2 processes on this server. Everything was working fine until a few weeks ago where I had a user rollback the server due to some issues. The user also had to restart the pm2 processes. Since then I am not able to find the running pm2 processes anymore though I do know they are running as the application running off these pm2 processes is still working.
When I type in pm2 ls to see what the processes running are I get the following warning:
[PM2][WARN] Current process list is not synchronized with saved list. App sampleprocess1 sampleprocess2 differs. Type 'pm2 save' to synchronize.

When I type in pm2 save to synchronize I get the following warnings:
[PM2] Saving current process list...
[PM2][WARN] PM2 is not managing any process, skipping save...
[PM2][WARN] To force saving use: pm2 save --force

How can I navigate around this as I need to make some changes to the codebase and will eventually need to restart the pm2 processes running?

Running pm2 save with empty process list would erase your saved processes, fortunately pm2 prevents you from doing that.
To manually bring back previously saved processes (via pm2 save):
pm2 resurrect

...that will restore your processes. Then I recommend running:
pm2 save
pm2 startup

Then copy and run the command that "pm2 startup" shows you.
Source: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/
Now processes will automatically start on system reboot & startup.
Note: it seems 'pm2 startup' is only for linux. For a windows alternative, check the link above
